# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Why do I get an error (ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')) in this case when I add to the request "{ observe: 'response' }"? For to get all headers.

```
    let answer = this.http.post<ResponseLoginHttp>(AUTH_API + "login", json_data, { observe: 'response' });
let answer2
answer.subscribe(value => {
  this.dataService.setResponceLoginHttp(value.body);
  answer2 = value.body
})
return answer2.pipe(
  map((data) => {
    return data;

  }),
  catchError((error) => {
    console.log("Error - ", error);
    throw new Error(error.message);
  })
);}
```

In case I don't use "{ observe: 'response' }" Everything is fine:

```
    let answer = this.http.post<ResponseLoginHttp>(AUTH_API + "login", json_data );
answer.subscribe(value => {
  this.dataService.setResponceLoginHttp(value);
})
return answer.pipe(
  map((data) => {
    return data;

  }),
  catchError((error) => {
    console.log("Error - ", error);
    throw new Error(error.message);
  })
);}
```

how can i get all the headers from the response without having an error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')"?

Comment: The problem is not from `{ observe: 'response' }`. Compare the first code and second ode, you are trying to assign value to `answer2` in `answer.subscribe` which is async operation. So it doesn't wait for it to be completed, but it proceeds to next line which `answer2` is null.  An easy way to test it by placing `console.log(/* some value */)` in both inner `answer.subscribe` and after it. You will see that the `console.log()` after `answer.subscribe` will print first then follow by `console.log()` in `answer.subscribe`  when the response is returned.

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with your `{observe: 'response'}`

When you do this :

```js
let answer = this.http.post<ResponseLoginHttp>(AUTH_API + "login", json_data, { observe: 'response' });
let answer2
answer.subscribe(value => {
  this.dataService.setResponceLoginHttp(value.body);
  answer2 = value.body
})
return answer2.pipe(
```

You call `answer2` outside the subscribe and your answer2 is not yet defined. The subscribe is an async tool, js will not wait the response to execute the next lines. Plus your `answer2` will never be an `Observable`.

You have to do something like this:

```js
this.http.post<ResponseLoginHttp>(AUTH_API + "login", json_data, { observe: 'response' })
    .pipe(
        map((response: HttpResponse<ResponseLoginHttp>) => {
            // Here you can do something with response.headers
            return response.body;
        })      
     )
    .subscribe(
        value => this.dataService.setResponceLoginHttp(value),
        error => {
            console.log("Error - ", error);
            throw new Error(error.message);
        });
```

Or simpler:

```js
this.http.post<ResponseLoginHttp>(AUTH_API + "login", json_data, { observe: 'response' })
    .subscribe(
        response => {
            // Here you can do something with response.headers
            this.dataService.setResponceLoginHttp(response.body);
        }),
        error => {
            console.log("Error - ", error);
            throw new Error(error.message);
        });
```